# c++ object copy inside vector element repeats more than expected

Tags: c++, object, vector, stl

I created TWO objects of a dummy class and pushed them into vector. But I see somehow the constructor works FIVE times. I am confused. can someone help?

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int obj_id=1;

class dummy {
int d;
public:

dummy()// default constructor :
{ 
    d=obj_id++; 
    cout<< "dummy created :" << d <<" \n"; 
}

dummy(const dummy & du) // copy constructor :
{
    d=obj_id++; 
    cout<< "dummy copy created :" << d <<" \n"; 
}
~dummy() { cout<< "dummy destroyed :" << d << " \n"; }
};

void generate(vector<dummy> &v) {
   for(int i=0;i<2;i++)
   {
       dummy x;
       v.push_back(x);
       cout<< "pushed into vector \n";
   }
   return ;
}   

int main ()
{
vector <dummy> vd;
generate(vd);
cout<<" Created dummies \n";

return 0;
}
=========================
Output:
dummy created :1 
dummy copy created :2 
pushed into vector 
dummy destroyed :1 
dummy created :3 
dummy copy created :4 
dummy copy created :5 ** how this comes **??
dummy destroyed :2 ** oops.. how the copy inside vector destroyed?
pushed into vector 
 destroyed :3 
 Created dummies 
dummy destroyed :4 
dummy destroyed :5
```

the even numbered dummies are supposed to be vector element copies. But how 5th dummy appears? how does the 2nd dummy (first element of vector) gets destroyed before returning from function?

Answer (score 2):

Open a debugger and keep an eye on the capacity of your vector as you step over each line in your `generate()` loop. When first created, it has a capacity of 0. It will automatically increase the capacity as needed, but it actually destroys the existing elements and recreates them under the covers. This is what causes the extra create/destroy that you are seeing.

Add `vd.reserve(2);` after declaring your vector, and this extra create/delete will go away.

Comment: perfect. Thank you.
after I setup the initial vector capacity, the problem went away.
vd.reserve(2);

Answer (score 2):

When the second `dummy` object is pushed into the vector the vector is too small to hold all the dummy objects and gets resized which results in the additional copy constructor calls.

You can prevent this by increasing the initial vector capacity using `vd.reserve(10)` for example.

Comment: perfect. Thank you.
after I setup the initial vector capacity to 2, the problem went away.
     vd.reserve(2);